# Migrating compileSdkVersion 22 to 23 without giving marshmallow support

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an android application. its `minSdkVersion` is 14 and `compileSdkVersion` level is 22. I saw that google has released support library version 23.+ and I am using 22.2.2 for updating this my `compileSdkVersion` should be 23, currently I am not planning to support **Marshmallow**. so can I directly change `compileSdkVersion` version to 23 ? or should I support Marshmallow (`Runtime permissions and all`).

Answer (score 2):

"targetSdkVersion 22" is all you need. As you can see in the official documentation (http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)  it says:

> "If the device is running Android 5.1 or lower, or your app's target
>   SDK is 22 or lower: If you list a dangerous permission in your
>   manifest, the user has to grant the permission when they install the
>   app; if they do not grant the permission, the system does not install
>   the app at all. If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and
>   your app's target SDK is 23 or higher: The app has to list the
>   permissions in the manifest, and it must request each dangerous
>   permission it needs while the app is running."

Comment: you can use the compileSdkVersion 23 without giving support to marshmallow. the only thing you must do is setting your targetSdkVersion to 22 or lower

Comment: that seems to be fine, but do you have any documentation for this ?

Comment: i use this in several apps and it works. However the link in my answer should answer your question

Comment: it says "If the device is running Android 5.1 or lower, or your app's target SDK is 22 or lower: If you list a dangerous permission in your manifest, the user has to grant the permission when they install the app; if they do not grant the permission, the system does not install the app at all.
If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target SDK is 23 or higher: The app has to list the permissions in the manifest, and it must request each dangerous permission it needs while the app is running."